# ODB With PostgreSQL bad_alloc Exception

Tags: c++, postgresql, dll, qt-creator, odb

I tried to to use ODB within my project. Therefore I used VS2015 to compile the windows sources for their odb and odb-pgsql library choosing the Release and x64 configuration. I linked the libraries from my standard postgres installation(prebuilt binaries 64bit).

My project is managed by cmake and QtCreator. Here is the compiler setup from the Kit I use.

[image: kit configuation in QtCreator]

I set up a very simple project that replicates the error. Here is the CMakeLists.txt

```
project(minimal_odb CXX)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(
  "C:/Users/micha/Downloads/libodb-2.4.0/libodb-2.4.0/"
  "C:/Users/micha/Downloads/libodb-pgsql-2.4.0/libodb-pgsql-2.4.0/")
add_executable(exec main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(exec
  "C:/Users/micha/Downloads/libodb-2.4.0/libodb-2.4.0/lib64/odb.lib"
  "C:/Users/micha/Downloads/libodb-pgsql-2.4.0/libodb-pgsql-2.4.0/lib64/odb-pgsql.lib")
```

Running cmake will print the used compiler.

```
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.23506.0
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
```

here the main.cpp

```
#include "odb/pgsql/database.hxx"

int main() {
  const std::string pg = "postgres";
  ::odb::pgsql::database db(pg, pg, pg, pg, 0);
  return 0;
}
```

Already during compiliation I get confusing warnings.

[image: compiler warnings]

At runtime the DLLs are found from the modified path environemt

```
C:\Users\micha\Downloads\libodb-2.4.0\libodb-2.4.0\bin64;
C:\Users\micha\Downloads\libodb-pgsql-2.4.0\libodb-pgsql-2.4.0\bin64
```

However my program instantly terminates with a bad_alloc exception. I debugged the application and here is my call stack.

[image: callstack during debugging]

The error occurs just when the string is copied into a local `user_` variable from `::odb::pgsql::database`.

If I go deeper into the copy assignment I can see the handed string from my main is not really setup and points to 0x0 reading random values from memory.

[image: stack values in assign operation]

The application prints the following to my terminal.

```
Exception at 0x7ffd148d1f08, code: 0xe06d7363: C++ exception, flags=0x1 (execution cannot be continued) (first chance) at f:\dd\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\heap\throw_bad_alloc.cpp:33

Exception at 0x7ffd148d1f08, code: 0xe06d7363: C++ exception, flags=0x1 (execution cannot be continued) (first chance) at f:\dd\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\heap\throw_bad_alloc.cpp:33

Exception at 0x7ffd148d1f08, code: 0xe06d7363: C++ exception, flags=0x1 (execution cannot be continued) (first chance) at c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xstring:2185

Exception at 0x7ffd148d1f08, code: 0xe06d7363: C++ exception, flags=0x1 (execution cannot be continued) (first chance) in ntdll!RcConsolidateFrames

Exception at 0x7ffd148d1f08, code: 0xe06d7363: C++ exception, flags=0x1 (execution cannot be continued) in ntdll!RcConsolidateFrames
```

I do not wonder getting a `bad_alloc` with this `_Num` value but I wonder why my string is messed up. I tried some different compiler like the `amd64` and compiled odb, odb-pgsql using UNICODE and Multi-Byte character-set but nothing helped. At least using the `amd64` I did not get the first 5 warnings mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Does it help to change `const std::string pg = "postgres";` to `std::string pg = "postgres";`?

Otherwise it looks like a linking problem.(Will edit/delete answer if this does not help)